# unable to boot after installation : freeBSD

Tags: ubuntu, freebsd, grub2, grub

I have Ubuntu installed in my system. I just installed FreeBSD 10.0 in to my system.

Here is the screenshot of GParted.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Where `/dev/sda1` is where my Ubuntu is installed, and `/dev/sda4` is where I install FreeBSD. **NOTE:** Installation of FreeBSD is clean.

But when I restart the system, all the time it is starting Ubuntu only.

Comment: FreeBSD may have trouble running in 4GB, but I believe you need to boot into Ubuntu and `update-grub` so that the `os-prober` can add FreeBSD

Comment: @eyoung100 : It is installed in dev/sda4 , sorry . edited.

Comment: OK, you still need to login to Ubuntu and Update Grub

Comment: @eyoung100 : can you please tell me how or give me some links

Comment: grub updated , with "unrecgonized linux found at /dev/sda4 freeBSD".

Comment: You have an unknown file system on /dev/sda4. What should the filesystem be? Or what did you set it as?

Comment: According to [Chapter 2 Section 6 of the FreeBSD Install Manual](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/bsdinstall-partitioning.html), that type should be `freebsd-ufs`.  See [this blog](http://blog.leahhanson.us/notes-on-installing-and-booting-freebsd-from-grub2.html).  Apparently, OS Prober and GParted don't support UFS.  As such, add it manually.

Comment: @eyoung100 , it is of the type freeBSD - ufs2.

Comment: I'm not disputing that but your going to have to add a custom entry to Grub2 [like so](http://blog.leahhanson.us/notes-on-installing-and-booting-freebsd-from-grub2.html), using `/etc/grub.d/40_custom ` and remove the entry created by `os-prober`

Comment: @eyoung100 , done! now , grub is showing me "error: no such partition".

Comment: Use `gdisk` to determine the GPT Partition, then `update-grub` and reboot.  `fdisk` doesn't understand GPT schemes.